# Why is the representation in the ring of formal power series unique?

Tags: ring-theory, generating-functions

I wonder of course why equality of the generating functions can be used in order to prove the equality of the series.

Comment: [previously answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2334657/561348) You need, of course, equality on a sufficiently large set of points. Where a sequence of different points converging to the origin is an example of large.

Comment: But what happens when the sum converges only for 0?

Comment: Then no. The series $\sum_{n\geq0}n!x^n$ and $\sum_{n\geq0}(n!)^2x^n$ converge only for $x=0$ and for $x=0$ they are both equal to $1$, but they don't have the same coefficients.

Comment: But they are not equal as formal power series. Maybe the uniqueness in this meaning is completely trivial.

Comment: That is exactly the point of the example and what you asked in your second comment. The two series converge only at $x=0$ (their center), their value there is the same, but they are not the same series.

Comment: I am troubled by actions on generating functions that need justification and assume some sort of uniqueness. E.g. infinitely many reductions (this was explained somewhere). Or saying f(x)g(x)=h(x)g(x) -> f(x)=h(x) (this too is easy).